# Botón que busque una palabra/s en un textbox y la/s resalte?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, botón

He creado un programa con el que abro un archivo .txt y me muestra su contenido en un textBox. Ahora me gustaría hacer otro botón que busque una palabra/s dentro de este textBox y la/s resalte, de manera que yo escriba dicha palabra en otro textBox o de otra manera si es que la hay. Adjunto codigo;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string[] listaFicheros {get;set;}
    private int indiceFichero {get;set;}
    string AddValues(string derecha, string izquierda)
    {
        return derecha + izquierda;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        mailSpam objeto = new mailSpam();


        using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
            {
                listaFicheros = objeto.obtenerListadoDirectorio(fbd.SelectedPath);
                if (listaFicheros.Length > 0)
                {
                    indiceFichero = 0;
                    try
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(listaFicheros[indiceFichero]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }


    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        indiceFichero++;

        if (indiceFichero > listaFicheros.Length-1)
        {
            indiceFichero=0;
        }

        try
        {
            textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(listaFicheros[indiceFichero]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }


    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        indiceFichero--;

        if (indiceFichero > listaFicheros.Length - 1)
        {
            indiceFichero = 0;
        }

        try
        {
            textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(listaFicheros[indiceFichero]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Este seria el boton buscar
    }



}
```

}

Comment: Me temo que no es posible. En un `TextBox` no hay posibilidad de cambiar el estilo, probablemente debas usar un `RichTextBox`

Comment: Vaya hombre... Y puedo hacer que me busque una palabra y me muestre toda la linea en la que aparece esa palabra a otro textBox?

Comment: Eso si es posible. Simplemente puedes usar `IndexOf` en la propiedad text de tu textbox por ejemplo, y extraer el texto entre dos `Environment.NewLine` que contenga esa palabra.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias voy a intentarlo así.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/107743/17237) fue mi respuesta a alguien buscando algo parecido.

Sólo que en este caso en lugar de usar la variable para buscar el texto, lo tomaría desde otro TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el método [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) para saber si el TextBox contiene el texto que le pases:

```
if (textBox1.Text.Contains(textPalabra.Text))
{
    //CÓDIGO
}
```

Comment: Y para que coja la palabra que yo escriba en textBox en vez de escribirla en el codigo?

Comment: Pones donde pone `"TEXTO"` el nombre del `textbox.Text`